# How do I create a simple Web Server using WCF without the ServiceHost class?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, channelfactory

I've began to learn WCF and wish to understand its internals by creating a simple Web server using channel stacks directly. I have found a lot of theory in the web but I'd like to see a working sample code of receiving and responding an httprequest that I can test using any browser. 
 I'm hoping for something that shows the setup of a custom binding by assembling binding elements all the way to responding the request.

Comment: Not sure - the ServiceHost is responsible for spinning up and initializing the entire WCF runtime server-side - not sure if you **really** want to duplicate all that code..... what's the point, really? Seems like re-inventing a fairly complex and very intricate runtime system - what do you want to gain from that??

Comment: I don't think what I want to do is very complex, I found a sample in here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789029(VS.90).aspx - but could'nt get it to work. By no means I intend to use this in production, I just like to understand the pieces that makes WCF.

Comment: "Because I want to know how it works" is as good a reason as any to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer in MSDN forums :

```
static void RunService()
    {
      //Step1: Create a custom binding with just TCP.
      BindingElement[] bindingElements = new BindingElement[2];
      bindingElements[0] = new WebMessageEncodingBindingElement();
      bindingElements[1] = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

      CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElements);


      //Step2: Use the binding to build the channel listener.     
      IChannelListener<IReplyChannel> listener =
         binding.BuildChannelListener<IReplyChannel>(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/channelapp"),
          new BindingParameterCollection());

      //Step3: Listening for messages.
      listener.Open();
      Console.WriteLine(
          "Listening for incoming channel connections");

      //Wait for and accept incoming connections.
      IReplyChannel channel = listener.AcceptChannel();
      Console.WriteLine("Channel accepted. Listening for messages");

      //Open the accepted channel.
      channel.Open();

      //Wait for and receive a message from the channel.
      RequestContext request= channel.ReceiveRequest();

      //Step4: Reading the request message.
      Message message = request.RequestMessage;
      Console.WriteLine("Message received");
      Console.WriteLine("To: {0}", message.Headers.To); // TO contains URL from the browser including query string  
      if (!message.IsEmpty) // HTTP GET does not contain body
      {
        string data = message.GetBody<string>();
        Console.WriteLine("Message content: {0}", data);
      }

      //Send a reply - You can control reply content based on message.Header.To or by message content
      Message replymessage = Message.CreateMessage(binding.MessageVersion, 
        "http://contoso.com/someotheraction", XElement.Parse("<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>"));

      // Set reply content type
      HttpResponseMessageProperty property = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
      property.Headers[System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
      replymessage.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = property;

      request.Reply(replymessage);

      //Step5: Closing objects.
      //Do not forget to close the message.
      message.Close();
      //Do not forget to close RequestContext.
      request.Close();
      //Do not forget to close channels.
      channel.Close();
      //Do not forget to close listeners.
      listener.Close();
    }
```

(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/09b620e0-ea81-4a6c-8a10-02a032ccd821)

Comment: This runs nicely in LINQPad (https://Linqpad.net) but you do need the following using : System.Runtime.Serialization, System.ServiceModel.Channels, System.ServiceModel, System.ServiceModel.Web.  
Great sample code.